# How to stop JComponent.setLocation() from causing a repaint?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to achieve camera shake for my game by randomly setting the location of the JPanel which everything in the game is drawn on. After a bit of experimentation, I am certain that `JPanel.setLocation(Point p)` triggers a repaint, which I don't want to happen.

So the way I create screen shake is by specifying the intensity and the frames it should last. However, the effect always wore off far too quickly, so I did some experimentation. I found that the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of the JPanel was triggered multiple times within one frame, but only while there was screen shake (how really does not add much to the point).

This is how the effect is generated:

```
public void display(){
  framesAlive++; //<-- used to track when the effect has worn off
  int intensityX = (int) (Math.random() * vals[0] - vals[0] / 2);
  int intensityY = (int) (Math.random() * vals[0] - vals[0] / 2);
  pane.setLocation(new Point(intensityX, intensityY));
}
```

And this is the simplified version of the `paintComponent` method:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
  super.paintComponent(g);
  for (int i = 0; i < stockEffects.size(); i++) {
    stockEffects.get(i).display(g);
  }
}
```

Again, my guess is that `setLocation()` causes a repaint, which basically results in an infinite loop in which the `paintComponent()` method triggers the `display()` function, which triggers `setLocation()`, which triggers a repaint that starts the whole cycle again. This results in the `framesAlive` variable being incremented multiple times per frame, which throws the whole timing system off. Is there an elegant way to solve this?

Comment: `method triggers the display() function` - custom painting is for painting only . You should NOT be changing the state of the component. Instead you use setter methods to change the state (ie, the location of a component) and then you invoke repaint() on the panel.

Comment: @camickr I know, but there actually is a lot more in the ```display(Graphics g)``` method for doing other stuff than I'm showing here. It makes sense to put it in there in my case, trust me.

Comment: *It makes sense to put it in there in my case* - You should NOT be changing state in a painting method, plain and simple. This shows you have a poor design and do not understand how Swing works. *This results in the framesAlive variable being incremented multiple times per frame* - exactly! You are NOT in control of when the painting method is called. You can't control when the user might do something causing the frame to be repainted. Generating random values (ie changing state) in a painting method is just wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use AffineTransform. this don't have to change objects real location.

it just change how to draw.
you can shake, rotate, flip, scale etc....

```
public static void main (String[] arg) {
    MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}

public static class MainFrame extends JFrame{
    public MainFrame() {
        this.setSize(600,600);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();
        this.add(mainPanel);
    }
}

public static class MainPanel extends JPanel{
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        // Panel Size = 400 X 400
        g.drawLine(200, 0, 200, 400); // Y Axis
        g.drawLine(0, 200, 400, 200); // X Axis

        // Create Transform
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.translate(200, 200); // Move Center Form (0, 0) To JPanel Center (200, 200)

        // Change Transform 
        at.translate(-200, 0); // Move Center

        // Set Transform To Graphics2D
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setTransform(at);

        // Draw Rectangle By Graphics2D
        g2d.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I never thought about using an AffineTransform! I always forget how much you can do with these things...